Cookies Not Clearing on Logout with Tomcat 9
I recently upgraded my application from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9 and am experiencing an issue with cookies not being cleared
Relevant Code:
Here's how I'm handling the logout and cookie clearing:
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("UniToken", "");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);

New Environment Details: Tomcat 9, JDK 8
Old Environment Details: Tomcat 8, JDK 8
Troubleshooting Done:

Verified that the cookie path and other settings are identical in both environments.
Checked Tomcat configurations (server.xml, context.xml, web.xml) and they are consistent across both environments.
Added logs to track cookie values, which confirmed that the cookie should be cleared as specified.

Could this be related to Tomcat's configuration when upgrading from Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9 ?
